# Why is line number wrong in error stack trace in sveltekit app?

Tags: javascript, logging, stack-trace, sveltekit, line-numbers

If I generate a sveltekit app skeleton with

```bash
npm create svelte@latest lineno
cd lineno
npm install
```

And then create a hooks handler script with a trivial handler generates an error myself, I get the wrong line number (4 instead of 2):

```
export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
  console.log(new Error("My error").stack)
  return await resolve(event);
}
```

```bash
Error: My error
    at Object.handle (/erikor/Documents/Business/lineno/src/hooks.server.js:4:15)
```

(Interestingly, actual code errors caught by the runtime report the correct line numbers, as one would expect.)

Why is the stack trace line number different when I create a new error compared to when there is an error in my code causing the error to be thrown?  And is there a way to get the correct line numbers?

Comment: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/10579 is very similar, and sveltekit 1.25.1 fixed line numbers in server traces.